# How to disable & enable the JTAG fuse in code on AtXmega MCU?

Tags: avr, xmega, atxmega

An application sheet suggested that by disabling the JTAG interface fuse (JTAGEN) the current consumption of the MCU will drop a bit. Can this be done from within the code itself?

Comment: You can disable JTAG with the JTAGD bit in MCUCR. Not sure if this will have the same power saving effect or not. Do you have a reference for the power savings?

Comment: XMegas can not self-write fuses (neither code in bootloader section). You need external programmer to modify them. But, as already mentioned, you can disable JTAG temporarily until next reset by bit in MCUCR register.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable JTAG with the JTAGD bit in MCUCR. Not sure if this will have the same power saving effect or not.

Answer (score 1):

It can be disabled in Microchip Studio Program.  Go to "tools", "device Programming", "Fuses" and look for FUSEBYTE4JTAGEN and uncheck the box.  This is for the ATXMEGA flavors, not sure on the AVR flavors

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the JTAG fuse (or any fuse on an AVR) in software.

You can however disable the JTAG interface at runtime by setting the `JTAGD` bit in the `MCUCR` register.

Here is code to do that...

```
// Disable JTAG interface as per 4.18.6

void inline disableJTAG() {

    CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;          // Enable change to IOREG 
    MCU.MCUCR = MCU_JTAGD_bm;    // Setting this bit will disable the JTAG interface
}
```

Note that I tested this code on an ATXMEGA64B3 and disabling the JTAG this way did not seem to have a measurable impact on power usage. I measured 0.8uA @ 3V for sleeping with the bit set and not set. The resolution of my meter is 0.1uA (100nA).

Also also tried disabling the JTAG by clearing the `JTAGEN` fuse bit using a an external programmer and this also did not have any measurable impact on sleep power usage.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe so. The point of fuse bits is a permanent setting usually done at a factory. I haven't looked into this however.

Comment: This is not an answer.